# Passing Multiple Models to a Template under a single context_object_name

Tags: python, django

I am making a blog frontpage, and want to create a single list of posts from multiple models in chronological order.  So far I have:

/videos/models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slugline = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    link = models.URLField()
....
```

/articles/models.py:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slugline = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_pics/')
```

home/views.py:

```
class FrontPage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'front_articles_list'
    queryset = Video.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FrontPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['articles'] = Content.objects.filter(
        published_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-published_date')[:5]
    context['videos'] = Video.objects.filter(
        published_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-published_date')[:5]
    return context
```

In my template, index.html, I am referencing the data like this:

```
{{ front_articles_list.0.title }}
{{ front_articles_list.0.published_date }}

{{ front_articles_list.1.title }}
```

, etc.

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, because I want to be able to have a list of the five most recent posts, whether they're videos, articles, or, likely, a mix of both, and the two models don't share the same fields.

I tried using a for loop for these, but it really screwed up my formatting. It just seemed easier for the way the page was set up to insert the data this way.

The second problem with this is that my page is displaying the oldest post first, not the newest, and it's only pulling from the Video model -- I'm assuming because it's the one listed in the queryset variable in the FrontPage view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to do is to query the most recent 5 of each of your models, then sort them together in Python. You'd won't be a queryset, so there will be no point using a ListView: a standard template view is all you need.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    articles = Article.objects.order_by("-published_date")[:5]
    videos = Video.objects.order_by("-published_date")[:5]
    items = list(articles) + list(videos)
    items.sort(key=lambda i: i.published_date, reverse=True)
    return {"items": items[:5]}
```

Comment: Sorry for noobness, but I'm not sure how to implement this with a standard view

Comment: Did I not show you what you need to do? What else do you need?

Comment: Well as it is, I am assuming I replace my get_context_data function with yours. I'm just a little confused about what the standard template view would look like, if I should to go a function-based view or if it would still be class-based, bust mostly if I would still use the {{ front_articles_list.0.title }} format in my templates